# center aligned special symbol

Tags: html, css

[image]Here the CSS and HTML code is :

CSS:

```
. d {
    display: table;
    } 
.c {
   font-size: 80px;
   display: table-cell; 
   vertical-align: super; 
   text-align: center;
   }
```

html:

```
  <div class="d"><p class="c">›</p>  </div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Note : `display: tabel` (notice the typo)

Comment: Do you want to center it within a table cell? Also fix the typo Vucko replied on

Comment: yes but this symbol is look like a underscore (_). take more space upside less downside

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4ZTR/) with your code. Take a look and see if this is what you wanted

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover please focus symbol in firebug it takes more space upper side and less space down side.. not in centered

Comment: It's pretty much vertically centered in @Chelseawillrecover's jsfiddle imho.

Comment: OK I see what you mean

Comment: please see the attached pic

Answer (score 1):

try this CSS:

```
.d {
     display: table;
     vertical-align:middle;
   }

.c {
     font-size: 80px;   
   }
```

There's a typo in your CSS mentioned ("tabel" instead of "table"). Also, there's a gap(white space) between "." (dot) & "d" class in first CSS style

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a second look at this question and I think using CSS may not render the symbol correctly or give desired result but does well for Text. Likely browser limitation.

I have 2 solutions here:

1.

Replace `vertical-align: super;`  with `vertical-align: middle;` then add position:relative; top:-2px;

```
. d {
 display: table;
} 
.c {
 font-size: 80px; 
 border: 1px solid  #666666;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position:relative; top:-2px;
}
```

2.

Using table renders better and gives desired result:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;border:1px solid  #666666; font-size: 80px">
          >
     </td>
  </tr>
</table
```

Check [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/enahaNu/2/edit) out for results.